# How do I set a singular check_box in formtastic using Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, formtastic

In my model

```
field :resizable, type: Boolean, default: true
```

Things I have tried in formtastic:

```
= f.input :resizable, :as => :check_boxes # This produces two textboxes
= f.input :resizable # This produces an input field
= f.input :resizable, :as => :check_box # This produces an error
```

The error I get on as: :check_box is:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Formtastic::UnknownInputError):
```

When I use, as: :radio it works.

Comment: Post what the error is please.

Comment: Hi Tyler, updated with my error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `:check_box` isn't a formtastic input. Also your form isn't bound to a model (from what I can see)

Just remove the :as param and you should be set.

Follow the example on Ryan Bates' screen cast [here](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1)

```
<% semantic_form_for @model do |f| %>  
  <% f.inputs do %>  
    <%= f.input :name %>  
    <%= f.input :born_on %>  
    <%= f.input :category %>  
    <%= f.input :female %>  
  <% end %>  
  <%= f.buttons %>  
<% end %>
```

If model has a field female which is a boolean then it will render as a checkbox. When you are specifying the `:as` arguement you are essentially overriding the default input type for that field.

Comment: That produces two.. I'll just got with radio buttons, thanks.

Comment: A radio is not the same thing as a checkbox and will function differently.

Comment: Updated my answer, check it out and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, that worked for Ryan because he was using ActiveRecord.  I think this is just an issue with formtastic not workign well with Mongoid.